# $state.go slow in large ng-repeat list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my view I have the following

```
<ul ng-repeat='item in items track by item.id>

   <li> <a ng-click='goToItem(item)'>View Item</a> </li>

</ul>
```

and in my controller then

```
$scope.goToItem = function(item) {

        $state.go('itemPost', { itemID: item.id, itemTitle: item.title});

    };
```

which works fine when the list is small enough.

However if it is a large list (say more than 150) the tranisition to the state is noticeably slow, taking maybe 2 or 3 seconds to change state.

Any suggestions as to how to speed up the transitiion?

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces the problem

Comment: maybe `<a ui-sref="itemPost({ itemID: item.id, itemTitle: item.title})">` would be a bit faster as it doesn't require an additional function to be defined and called.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Paolo, have already tried that however to no effect!